# GWT dev mode not only on localhost for mobile application development

Tags: gwt, mobile-website

I need to debug and test a mobile web-application.

How to setup a working GWT development mode for mobile application development to enable a fast development environment? I would like that GWT-hosted mode could be executed on an iphone browser. Is there a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT development mode requires a plugin in the browser to translate between Java source and JavaScript running in the browser. Since the iPhone browser doesn't support plugins at all it is not possible to use development mode on an iPhone.

You should be able to use a WebKit browser (Safari or Chrome), resized to the approximate dimensions of the iPhone, to test the layout of your application. You'll still have to perform a full compile when testing iPhone specific features (gestures, etc.).

Comment: Is the full compile a production version? Do you need to instantiate the static generated on a tomcat server, for example?  Can you detail more on the steps to achieve the interface testing on a mobile browser as quickly/efficient as possible?